# Kohya_SS and multiple python versions

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, dreambooth

```
10:20:10-098640 ERROR    The current version of python is not appropriate to run
                         Kohya_ss GUI                                           
10:20:10-098956 ERROR    The python version needs to be greater or equal to     
                         3.10.9 and less than 3.11.0                            
Validation failed. Exiting...
```

*I keep getting the error though I am sure I installed multiple Python Version and could switch to one it is suppose to use??*

```
user@Name-MacBook-Pro ~ % alias python3="python3.10"
user@Name-MacBook-Pro ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.10.14
```

to train a Model over Dreambooth/Lora interface I was able to open a day before

Comment: this (rather stringent) criteria needs to be satisfied: `The python version needs to be greater or equal to 3.10.9 and less than 3.11.0`.